# grep : sort strings CASE INSENSITIVE which end or begin with specific letter

Tags: linux, grep, scripting, io-redirection

i have a file names.txt, now i want to store all the names that start with D in another file startWithD.txt and store all the names that end with E in another file endsWithE.txt (the search being case-insensitive).

i have tried this

```
grep -i '^D' names.txt >> startsWithD.txt
grep -i 'e$' names.txt >> endsWithE.txt
```

Comment: Check your `sort` man page for the `--ignore-case` option => `grep ... | sort ... > file`

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. Perhaps add to the answer what output you got, and what you expected instead?
Should contributors assume file-per-line in names.txt?